# Unable to accept lead from lead list view in one step

Tags: workflow

When I try to accept lead from list view, I am having two steps in between.

When lead is accepted from list,the lead changes to Active.

The workflow defined is :

```
AND 
(ISCHANGED( OwnerId ), 
PRIORVALUE( OwnerId )="00Gj0000000Ltz0")
```

**Field Update** -> `Lead Status = Active`

which makes lead acceptance two steps

step 1: lead status changes to active

step 2: lead owner changes . When I try to deactivate this,the acceptance does not occur at all.

Please let me know so that lead status and lead acceptance happens in one step.

Regards,
Kunal